# Using Ethereum as a Unique ID Generator

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, golang

I have a requirement where I would like to call a smart contract and store some values against a unique ID.

I have seen the `Counters` library from OpenZeppelin.

Is a smart contract a good use case for this? This could potentially get thousands of requests coming in - I only really care about sequential Ids. (as an alternative to generating a primary key in sql)

Can I just increment the counter?

Can I be sure that I won't have the same counter generated twice even when I scale out the system that calls this contract?

EDIT:

example:

`using Counters for Counters.Counter;`

and then in the solidity external method

get the id by doing

`_auctionIdCounter.increment();`

`assign the id to a mapping`

Comment: Please, can you include an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Ethereum uses a Proof of Work consensus algorithm. This implies that the transaction order isn't final immediately. These changes are called "chain reorganizations".

If we suppose you increase the counter in a transaction. A chain reorg will cause that some transactions might be executed in a different order. For example if a transaction TX1 get counter = 100 and TX2 counter = 101, if they are reordered TX2 counter = 100 and TX1 counter = 101.